Reading Parquets From S3 With Apache Spark Slows Down At Later Stages
I have millions of parquets files on s3 with directory structure as code/day=xx/hour=/*.parquets.
At max under hour folder we have 2000 parquest file with average size of 100kb.
I am not able to understand while reading and writing 90% of my data just taken few mins but for remaning 10% data it takes hours to process.Please suggest what exactly i am missing here
Spark Session
 SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("s3-clickhouse-data-migration")
                .master("local[*]")
                .config("fs.s3a.bucket.probe", "0")
                .config("fs.s3a.access.key", migrationConfigModel.accessKey())
                .config("fs.s3a.secret.key", migrationConfigModel.secretKey())
                .config("fs.s3a.endpoint", migrationConfigModel.endPoint())
                .config("fs.s3a.experimental.input.fadvise", "random")
                .getOrCreate();

Reading parquet files from S3 (sourcePath: s3a://bucket_name/dir_name/dir_name/code=%s/days=%s/)
session.read().format(migrationConfigModel.getFormat()) .schema(structType)
                .option("inferSchema", false).parquet(sourcePaths.toArray(String[]::new));

Column mapping (doing it for 3-4 source key with desntinaion key(clickhouse db column name))
 df = df.withColumnRenamed(mapping.getSourceKey(), mapping.getDestinationKey());
      

Creating final dataset mapping to actual schema as per my db
df.select(Arrays.stream(fields)
                .map(StructField::name)
                .map(functions::col)
                .toArray(org.apache.spark.sql.Column[]::new));

then writing to DB
finalDF.write().mode(SaveMode.Append)
                    .option("isolationLevel", "NONE")
                    .option("batchsize", "10000")
                    .jdbc(migrationConfigModel.dbUrl(),
                    migrationConfigModel.tableName(), connectionProperties);

See below i have 28 million in total out of which 26 million records where updated under 40min but for rest it took more than 3.5 hours to process
Spark UI Jobs
I tried reparitioning and coalesce() varying the number of partition but nothing worked it start fast and slow down at stages at the end.
Please let me know what is to be done or what i am doing wrong here ?
System Details: Mode [Local] Cores[8] Ram[16GB]
Morever for the writing the data i am using Clickhouse native jdbc driver.

why do you need use Spark instead of read parquet files directly ?
INSERT INTO destination_table SELECT * FROM s3Cluster('your-clickhouse-cluster-name', 'https://endpoint/bucket/code/day=xx/hour=/*.parquets')
look
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/table-functions/s3Cluster
for details

its not only about inserting the data we have new columns in db for which i need join operation and for some others column some custom logic needs to run on source schema coloumns to extract the value.

try to increase .option("batchsize", "10000") to .option("batchsize", "1000000")
batch size 10000 is small for clickhouse

My bottleneck is not the writing to db but reading s3 files which is taking lot of time reading large number of small files so i tried merging them into few large files so its running quite fine now.
